# Cannot covert pandas index to datetime properly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hi I am trying to import csv file and set index as datetime obj. This is sample of csv:

```
date,wind_force,wind_dir,cloud_cover,temp
2019-01-01 04:00:00+01:00,13.9,234.0,100.0,3.8
2019-01-01 05:00:00+01:00,14.333333,239.33333,100.0,4.5333333
```

I import file and I try to use `pd.to_datetime` directly on my index:

```
dfw = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Path\weather.csv', index_col = 'date')
dfw.index = pd.to_datetime(dfw.index)
```

Then the `dfw.index` returns:

```
Index([2019-01-01 04:00:00+01:00, 2019-01-01 05:00:00+01:00,
      ......
       2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00, 2020-01-01 01:00:00+01:00],
      dtype='object', name='date', length=8750)
```

If i try `dfw.index.hour` I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

And when I use `utc = True` while changing index to datetime it converts it properly:

```
dfw.index = pd.to_datetime(dfw.index, utc = True)
```

But it return datetime in UTC and I want them to stay in previous timezone

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01 03:00:00+00:00', '2019-01-01 04:00:00+00:00',
              ...
               '2019-12-31 23:00:00+00:00', '2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='date', length=8750, freq=None)
```

What's also strange is when I try to call index by it's number like `dfw.index[33]` it returns:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 13, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

And then i can call dfw.index[33].hours etc.

So where's the gotcha here?

Comment: it's `dfw.index.dt.hour`,  does that help?

Comment: Unfortunetely not, it returns 'AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'dt''

Comment: You get the hint of the problem even earlier.  the "dtype" of index is object in the first case and not datetime64. Probabaly the issue remains somewhere in your original data. When i run the code with just the two lines of data you provided as an example, even the first method works for me.

Comment: @ Juan C, ".dt" would not work with index. If date was a non-index column, then it would have worked.

Comment: Well, at march there is time change from UTC+1 to UTC+2, so maybe there lies problem? But there are no bugs while importing so it is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
dfw.index = pd.to_datetime(dfw.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+01:00')
```

You are giving a precise format that enables you to conserve the timezone you are interested in. More information on letters for datetime format [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

**Edit:**
If you want to deal with summer / winter hours, you can replace `+01` by `+%f`

```
dfw.index = pd.to_datetime(dfw.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f:00')
dfw.index[0].hour # returns 4
```

Comment: Yeah it could help, however there is a time change in march, so the hardcoded format doesn't fit. Anyway thats for posting

Comment: No problem, what about with the edit? Not sure you'll be OK with it (you have temporal data) but it might solve your problem :)

Comment: Hmm with that I get:
ValueError: time data '2019-01-01 04:00:00+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+0?:00' (match)

Comment: Try to change `+0?` to `+%f` that is supposed to be for millisecond but that should do the trick

Comment: Yeah it worked. It leaves my index in a bit weird form (timezone element):
2019-04-11 00:00:00.020
But I will need only days and hours so it should be fine. Thanks ;)